# Connecting MS SQL server from Qt

Tags: sql, qt, sql-server-2012, odbc

Here is my code, which I have written using a book example.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("ODBC");
db.setHostName("DESKTOP-5ML5OT3");
db.setDatabaseName("Karine");
db.setUserName("DESKTOP-5ML5OT3");
db.setPassword("");
```

But I can't make a connection.There are a lot of linking errors.

Comment: Is the password actually empty, or are you obfuscating it for the question?

Comment: why don't you write down these linking errors?

Comment: main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase(void)" (__imp_??1QSqlDatabase@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "bool __cdecl createConnection(void)" (?createConnection@@YA_NXZ)

Comment: Meghan Armes - while connecting using windows authentication , the password field is grayed , and every time I connect without entering any password

Comment: Do you have sql in your project file?  (eg- QT += sql)